# Flink statebackend - how does parallelism work with RocksDB?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In the below code:

```
package spendreport;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.sink.AlertSink;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.entity.Alert;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.entity.Transaction;
import org.apache.flink.walkthrough.common.source.TransactionSource;

public class FraudDetectionJob {

   private String checkpointsDir  = "file://checkpoints/"
    private String rocksDBStateDir = "file://state/rocksdb/"


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.SetParallelism(3);     
        EnvironmentSettings tableSettings = EnvironmentSettings
            .newInstance()
               .useBlinkPlanner()
               .build();

       StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment
            .create(env, tableSettings);

      tableEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE Orders (`user` BIGINT, product STRING, amount INT) WITH (...)");

       env.enableCheckpointing(5000)
       env.checkpointConfig.minPauseBetweenCheckpoints = 100
       env.checkpointConfig.setCheckpointStorage(checkpointsDir)

       stateBackend = EmbeddedRocksDBStateBackend()
       stateBackend.setDbStoragePath(rocksDBStateDir)
       env.stateBackend = stateBackend


       DataStream<Transaction> transactions = env
            .addSource(new TransactionSource())
            .name("transactions");
        
        DataStream<Alert> alerts = transactions
            .keyBy(Transaction::getAccountId)
            .process(new FraudDetector())
            .name("fraud-detector");

        alerts
            .addSink(new AlertSink())
            .name("send-alerts");

        env.execute("Fraud Detection");
    }
}
```

---

Above job has parallelism set to 3. `env.SetParallelism(3)`

Does the operator  in each job access the same single RocksDB table(`Orders`)? to read or write records...

Or

Does parallelism(at job level) mean every job has its own RocksDB? Because RocksDB is per task manager and there is no guarantee if each job runs in same task manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RocksDB is not a networked service; it's an embedded key/value store. There are separate RocksDB instances in each task manager.

Comment: So, does each job has it's own RocksDB? Because here we have 3 parallel jobs...

Comment: Yes. I believe there's actually a separate RocksDB instance for each stateful task.

Comment: When you say, separate rocksDB instance for each stateful task..... say, within  a single job... If a task  partition stream  into 4 datastreams(using `keyBy()`) before running a stateful task for each partitioned stream, then,  does each job maintain 4 instances of RocksDB?

Comment: Possibly more than 4. Typically the source and sink are also stateful, so there might be 12 instances. But this is an implementation detail that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes. 4 RocksDB per job & 3 jparallel jobs. So total is 12. I need some clarificaition on `addSink()` api...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76925478/does-filesink-accumulate-data-across-partitions

Comment: I think the answer might be 36 (but I'm not sure): 3 jobs x 3 stateful operators per job x 4 slots per job.